# how to get cell's text on the nextview when click on a cell in uitableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I want to show the text from the uitablevicell selected to the nextview's navigationbar title. Any idea regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your delegate method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
nextViewController.title = cell.text;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Correction needed here in the given code above: The line should be read as UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] and not as indexpath.row.